# QGIS Map composer takes forever to render

Tags: qgis, print-composer, layouts, rendering

I have a project with several shapefiles, geopackages, rasters, and a XYZ tile map.

When I create a Print Layout the map composer takes really long times to render the maps, even when only 2 or 3 layers are to be shown with the XYZ tile.
Does anyone know the reasons for such issue?

Comment: You might turn different layers on and off to perhaps pin down if one of them is a problem layer.   If so add that info to your question.  Other info you might add is what coordinate systems are involved and what layout settings you are using.

Comment: @John I am using ESRI:102161 - Datum_73_Hayford_Gauss_IPCC. I wonder if this may be caused because I am accessing the project through a VPN server?

Comment: If you can copy the project and files to a local drive that likely would be faster, but how much depends on a lot of factors.  In my work I found it very difficult to run my powerful work computer over vpn, but I know another who found it slow but tolerable for creating new polys.  He used shapefiles.   I found that accessing file geodatabases over vpn to be very problematic; shapefiles much better, but geopackages I hadn't tried.  I preferred moving whole projects to my home work computer.  There is a plugin called QPackage that makes it easy to copy and move a whole project with data.  I

Comment: I did copy all my project and data to a local folder. The issue is slightly better but still not as desired, the map composer is still taking a long time to render the maps... So every time I change the extent or the scale it is a nightmare...

Comment: The rendering is roughly the same even with different layers on or off?  A  layer with lots of vertices, with snapping turned on, can create slow redraws.  One possible response to that is to generalize it.    The XYZ tile could be slow for some reason particularly if it has to be projected on the fly.  Mixing projections usually isn't an issue but slow rendering raises it as an issue. Perhaps a different server might help.  You can always check your layers for geometry errors whenever there are draw issues.  There are a few rendering settings you can adjust.